# Word for someone who does not like/want to get a job or do anything in life?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language, colloquialisms

In Portuguese, my native language, we have a lot of words for this kind of person, like *mandrião*, *calaceiro*, *calaça*, *indolente*, *malandro*, etc. We have also lighter words like *preguiçoso* that is the equivalent to "lazy" in English, but *lazy* has other meanings and can be used to someone that does things at low speed.

What words are there in English that have more aggressive power than "lazy", to call a person like that? I thought *loser* but that has other meanings as I see.

Comment: Slacker! (Anymore words would be "work"). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slacker

Comment: synonyms: *layabout, idler, shirker, malingerer, sluggard, laggard*; informal *lazybones, bum, goof-off*; *indolent, lazy, idle, slothful, loafing, do-nothing, sluggardly, shiftless, lackadaisical, languid, inactive, underactive, inert, sluggish, lethargic, torpid;     slack, good-for-nothing, feckless*

Comment: Intelligent people do not really think of human motivation in quite such dichotomous terms, so words like 'lazy', 'indolent' etc. are not much used by professionals nowadays. There are words which are used in the tabloid newspapers and easy enough to find if you pick one up at the newsstand.

Comment: In Australia, a *bludger*.

Comment: A related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158399/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-has-others-do-all-their-work-for-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia on Hobo:

Unlike "tramps"—who work only when they are forced to, and "bums"—who do not work at all, "hobos" are itinerant workers.

I think bum is the ideal word you want without sounding antiquated or too harsh. If you are looking for harsh, I'd go with "useless waste of space."

Comment: Sounding antiquated depends on how old you are. To Gen X and later, "slacker" is the proper word and "bum" used alone as a noun sounds archaic. It's only used as part of the phrase "lazy bum". "To bum" (something "off" of someone) on the other hand, is very widely used, as is "to be bummed" as a synonym for "disappointed".

Answer (score 7):

Such a person is referred to as an "Idler" or a "Loafer".

He is a person who avoids work or spends time in an aimless or lazy way.

Comment: Yes these are used and are pretty common.

Comment: Idler has been formed from the word 'Idle' and Loafer have always been commonly used.

Comment: I agree with Veronica Diamond on "loafer". It's quite common. "Lazybones" is also an informal term which refers to a lazy person.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia he'd be a [dole-bludger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dole-bludger).

Comment: Only if he's actually on the dole; Otherwise he's just a bludger.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

I would call him **aimless**, **lazy saint**, **dependent**.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is difficult.  At the moment we deride people who don't work.
They are slackers, benefit scroungers, parasites (on society?) - the language 
is aggressive & hate filled (filthy dossers) - but, of course, not so long ago, 
not working was a badge of honour.  The much loved Bertie Wooster had a London 
flat & a valet (Jeeves).  He had no intention of working but the Wodehouse 
novels are still in print nearly 100 years later ("My Man Jeeves" was published 
1n 1919).

So, the unemployed Wooster was a 'Playboy' or a 'Gentleman of Leisure' (although, in Moscow, in 1919, his status would have been unequivocal).

Comment: You took quite some trouble to post an answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

**a procrastinator**

To procrastinate until an opportunity is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In Northern Ireland we would call them "Lead swingers".

Answer (score 0):

Theres an acronym that describes them: NEET

Not in Employment, Education or Training

Comment: This sounds like a government classification, but it doesn't indicate whether or not the individual is in this condition intentionally.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Quotations, links and examples of usage can all improve an answer’s authoritativeness. Here’s a link you can start with: [“NEET” on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEET). See [How do I write a good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) section for more tips and tricks that can lead to upvotes.