# What is an appropriate word that describes someone who gets others to do things when they could easily do them themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

I'm trying to pin down a word or phrase that concisely describes a person who intentionally gets other people to do things for them that they could easily do themselves, as a form of either conscious or subconscious power-play.

A mix somewhere between being lazy, manipulative, exploitative, discourteous, and so on.

An example of how it would be used is, "Look at Stella being *...* again, lying on the couch and getting her father to get pass her the remote while he was sitting even further away from it than her!"

Comment: Relevant: [Is there a word for someone who has others do all their work for them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158399/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-has-others-do-all-their-work-for-them).

Comment: ... where answers like _drone / loafer / skiver / bludger / goof-off / shirker / parasite  / deadbeat / freeloader / leech / scrounge / sponge_ are offered.

Answer (score 0):

How about **entitled**?

> feeling that you have the right to do or have what you want without having to work for it or deserve it, just because of who you are:

*These kids are spoiled, entitled, self-absorbed, and apathetic.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's getting close to the mark, yet I still feel that entitled lacks a sense of manipulation